# Xcode 13 "Clean Build Folder ..." vs "Clean Build Folder Immediatly"

Tags: xcode

What differences, if any, exist between the "Clean Build Folder" action displayed in Xcode 14.3's "Product" menu by default and the action with the modified title "Clean Build Folder Immediately" that appears when the keyboard's "Option" key is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode's default "Clean Build Folder..." deletes the entire build folder including all artifacts of the build.

"Clean Build Folder Immediately" is analogous to the old "Clean", which deletes the contents of folders within the build folder. "Clean" is not as thorough as "Clean Build Folder..."

Historically, "Clean" was once the default option. Sometime after "Clean Build Folder..." became the default, "Clean" was hidden behind the "Option" key on the same menu button.

I see few reasons not to use the default "Clean Build Folder..." in most cases, although there may be some performance improvements with "Clean Build Folder Immediately" for rapid iteration.

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of 'selected files'?

Comment: @BlazejSLEBODA - I cannot clarify 'selected files', so I removed that phrase from my answer.